# how to set my custom timestamp in laravel?

Tags: laravel-4

how to change timestamp to myCustomTimestamp, for example jalali timestamp

e.g : 2015-10-6 convert to 1993-7-6 and saved as created_at or updated_at in database.

Comment: By custom timestamp do you mean use a custom format or just set a custom (arbitrary) date to it ?

Comment: Description is not clear enough. Can you please provide more details?

Comment: When I insert new data in tables, created_at and updated_at fill by 2014-XX-XX automatically(means Gregorian date), but I want fill by jalali date ,(1993-XX-XX)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find this laravel bundle, which would help you tackle jalali dates more easily - https://github.com/sallar/laravel-jdate .

I think, however, that the easier approach would be to specify your created_at and updated_at dates explicitly when doing insert/update operations, rather than extending the Eloquent class and overwriting the setUpdatedAt(), setCreatedAt() and updateTimestamps() methods (which I don't know, if it would even work and not break something).